# C# yield return enumerator, continue from part the way through

Tags: c#, iterator, yield, enumerable, enumerator

I am using yield return to process some data, with a non-deterministic set of iterations. I want to start processing, but break from the loop once a condition has been hit (e.g. byte size), pass the enumerator to a new thread that will continue to process, and then return the results processed so far.

In effect I have a foreach loop which I will likely break out of before the end. How can I pass the IEnumerable to a new thread and 'continue' from where I left off rather than the beginning?

```
public static IEnumerable<String> Process()
{
    // static values added for simplicity, but will be a variable number of returns
    yield return "1";
    yield return "2";
    yield return "3";
    yield return "4";
    yield return "5";
    yield return "6";    
}

List<String> main()
{
    List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
    IEnumerable<String> strList = Process();

    foreach(String strItem in strList)
    {
        retVal.Add(strItem);
        Console.WriteLine(strItem);
        // Time to send something back and continue in a new thread
        if (strItem.Equals("3"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }        

    new Thread(() => ThreadFunc(strList)).Start();
    return retVal;
}

public static void ThreadFunc(IEnumerable<String> strList)
{
    List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
    foreach(String strItem in strList)
     {
        retVal.Add(strItem);
        Console.WriteLine(strItem);
     }  
     // Send the rest of the data

}
```

Desired output: 1 2 3 4 5 6

Actual output: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6

Thank You.

Comment: You'd need something more complex (A type that keeps track of the current position) or pass the number of items to skip to the code that runs in the other thread.

Comment: @juharr: No; you just need an enumerator.

Comment: @SLaks Or that, but then you have to be careful to make sure you dispose of it properly.

Comment: @juharr If you're iterating the sequence multiple times it has numerous problems.  You're re-computing much of the generation of the sequence, and you're assuming that the contents of the sequence are going to be the same each time it's iterated, and also that it's even *possible* to iterate it multiple times, which often isn't the case.  Having to remember to dispose of the enumerator is simply what it takes to actually get the correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what the `IEnumerable<T>` interface actually does.

`IEnumerable<T>` is completely stateless; it just exposes a `GetEnumerator()` method, which hands back stateful enumerators that keep track of where they're up to.

You need to pass the same enumer*ator* instance between your two loops.  `foreach` can only operate on `IEnumerable<T>` (or similar), so you'll need to replace them with `while` loops that use `IEnumerator<T>` directly.

Make sure to dispose the `IEnumerator` in all codepaths (otherwise, `finally` or `using` blocks won't run).